# 3.0 Cakephp route html only

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I would like to route the urls that have the following pattern;

```
http://mywebsite.com/en/url.html
```

The code below works.

```
Router::prefix ( 'en', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions ( [ 
            'html' 
    ] );
    $routes->connect ( '/:page', [ 
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'view',
    ]
    , [ 
            'pass' => [ 
                    'page' 
            ] 
    ] );
    $routes->fallbacks ( 'InflectedRoute' );
} );
```

A problem arises for controllers that do not have html extension. for example

```
http://mywebsite.com/en/controller/
```

Is there a way to restrict

```
$routes->connect ( '/:page', [ 
        'controller' => 'Pages',
        'action' => 'view',
]
```

to pages that end with .html extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember this is not possible out of the box, you'll need additional logic that handles this in one way or another.

I'd say your best bet would be a [**custom route class**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes), which could not only restrict matching incoming URLs (`Route::parse()`), but also reverse routing (`Route::match()`).

You could simply test the extension of the URL (array) against the extensions defined via `RouteBuilder::extensions()` so that one of the parseable extensions is required, here's a very basic example:

**src/Routing/Route/MyCustomRoute.php**

```
namespace App\Routing\Route;

use Cake\Routing\Route\Route;

class MyCustomRoute extends Route {

    public function parse($url) {
        list(, $ext) = $this->_parseExtension($url);
        if(!in_array($ext, $this->extensions())) {
            return false;
        }
        return parent::parse($url);
    }

    public function match(array $url, array $context = []) {
        if(!isset($url['_ext']) || !in_array($url['_ext'], $this->extensions())) {
            return false;
        }
        return parent::match($url, $context);
    }

}
```

**config/routes.php**

```
// ...

$routes->connect('/:page', [
    'controller' => 'Pages',
    'action' => 'view',
], [
    'routeClass' => '\App\Routing\Route\MyCustomRoute',
    'pass' => ['page']
]);

// ...
```

This would cause only URLs with extensions to be parseable, and only URL arrays with an extension provided to be matched, ie

```
/en/page.html
['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'view', '_ext' => 'html']
```

would work, while

```
/en/page
/en/page.xml
['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'view']
['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'view', '_ext' => 'xml']
```

would not.

For further information see

- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#generating-urls**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#file-extensions**
- **http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Routing.Route.Route.html**

Answer (score 0):

not sure why it behaves like that, but i managed to restrict your route to .html file by setting a regex condition to :page.

`Router::prefix ( 'en', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions ( [ 
            'html' 
    ] );
    $routes->connect ( '/:page', [ 
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'view',
    ]
    , [ 
            'page' => '[0-9a-z]+',
            'pass' => [ 
                    'page' 
            ] 
    ] );
    $routes->fallbacks ( 'InflectedRoute' );
} );`

EDIT: the above solution does actually not work (see ndm comment). I did not manage to do what your are looking for with the routing system. What I suggest is to check the extension directly in your controller and throw a 404 error if it does not match "html".

Comment: This won't do what the OP is looking for, do not supply an extension and you'll see that the route will work just fine. What this will do is cause the route to not match in case a non `.html` extension is supplied, because in that case the extension will be part of the `:page` element, which won't pass the regex validation as it doesn't allow dots.